# No encoder has been configured for account "Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\Admin"

Tags: php, symfony

```
# security.yml 

security:
    encoders:
        Cl\AdminBundle\Entity\Admin:
            algorithm: sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 1


    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        cl_admin_security:
            id: cl_admin_security_provider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        admin_area:
            pattern:   ^/
            provider: cl_admin_security
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /security
                check_path: /security_check
                default_target_path: /admin
                username_parameter: _useremail
                password_parameter: _userpassword
            logout:
                path:   _demo_logout
                target: _demo

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/security, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }


# routing.yml 
_security_check:
    path: /security_check

_security:
    path: /security
    defaults: { _controller: ClSecurityBundle:Login:index }


// Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\Admin\ClSecurityProvider.php

namespace Cl\SecurityBundle\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\Admin;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;

class ClSecurityProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $em;
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
    /**
     * Loads the user for the given username.
     *
     * This method must throw UsernameNotFoundException if the user is not
     * found.
     *
     * @throws UsernameNotFoundException if the user is not found
     * @param string $username The username
     *
     * @return UserInterface
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $admin = $this->findUserBy(array("email" => $username));

        if (!$admin) {
            $message = sprintf(
                    'Unable to find an active admin ClCommonBundle:Admin object identified by "%s".', $admin
            );
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message);
        }
        return $admin;
    }
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $admin)
    {
        //return $this->loadUserByUsername($admin->getUsername());
        $class = get_class($admin);
        if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) { //This should be $class not $user
            $message = sprintf('Unsupported class type : %s', $class);
            throw new UnsupportedUserException($message);
        }
        return $this->find($user->getId());
    }
    /**
     * Whether this provider supports the given user class
     *
     * @param string $class
     *
     * @return Boolean
     */
    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class == "Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\Admin";
        //return $this->getEntityName() === $class || is_subclass_of($class, $this->getEntityName());
    }
    /**
     * findUserBy
     *
     * @param array $criteria
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function findUserBy(array $criteria)
    {
        $repository = $this->em->getRepository('Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\Admin');
        return $repository->findOneBy($criteria);
    }
}
```

---

I found an issue of No encoder has been configured for account "Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\Admin".

I have also implemented ClSecurityProvider in SecurityBundle\Security\ClsecurityProvider.php

Can anyone help me about this issue I am struck from 3-4 days.
I am not still complete custom authentication module.
I want to use my custom authentication code.

Comment: you question is unclear, please provide more informations /specifications

Comment: I want to create admin panel for my application. SO I used symfony 2.3 and do authentication using custom user providers. Now I got an error of No encoder has been configured for account "Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\Admin". you may read my code of providers ,security.yml, service.yml , routing.yml. Now I am include service.yml code also....

Comment: service.yml code.
parameters:
    cl_admin_security_provider.class: cl\SecurityBundle\Security\clSecurityProvider

services:
    cl_admin_security_provider:
        class: %cl_admin_security_provider.class%
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
        #arguments: [cl\CommonBundle\Entity\Admin]

Comment: Hi @Dipak.  I adjusted the format of your question so it displayed properly.  Are you really trying to implement a full blown custom authentication system like: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html or are you just trying to plug in your own UserProvider?  Big difference.

Comment: Can you post the Admin Entity and the relative "Manager" (where you try to create the user)?

Comment: Thanks Cerad for reply. Yes I want to create full blown custom authentication system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gp_sflower : now I can add all 3 models entity as well as fixtures. Please read my updated questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
encoders: 
    Cl\AdminBundle\Entity\Admin
```

Should be

```
encoders:
    Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\Admin
```

I should also point out that your title has “Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\Admin”.

Answer (score 0):

don't loose time coding the wheel :) ... try this admin bundle for symfony2 which is really great ....

here is a demo :

http://demo.sonata-project.org/admin/login ( login : admin / pass : admin )

and here is the official documentation

http://sonata-project.org/

we use this in all of our projects and manage the authentication with fosUserBundle which is also a "must have" bundle !!!

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle

Comment: Yes I referred both sonata & fos but I should try to create that stuff successfully once. I appreciate your response, but I wanted to implement this stuff myself.

Comment: @Dipak chavda Symfony2 have an hight learning curve especially if you coming from procedural coding and have a poor OOP knowledge. So if you have the time you need in any case an approfondite study of the Symfony2 Docs (expecially the Security component) also if you use some good bundle provided by others. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for that but how could I know without trial and I got this error for configuration so It doesn't matter of OOPs knowledge as my concern for present issue. I really thankful for your answer.